# Why does the Torah in Leviticus 21/23 use the word "Mikdoshay" in plural form?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash, mishkan-tabernacle, kedusha-holiness, sefer-vayikra

[אַ֣ךְ אֶל־הַפָּרֹ֜כֶת לֹ֣א יָבֹ֗א וְאֶל־הַמִּזְבֵּ֛חַ לֹ֥א יִגַּ֖שׁ כִּֽי־מ֣וּם בּ֑וֹ וְלֹ֤א יְחַלֵּל֙ אֶת־מִקְדָּשַׁ֔י כִּ֛י אֲנִ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה מְקַדְּשָֽׁם׃
but he shall not enter behind the curtain or come near the altar, for he has a defect. He shall not profane these places sacred to Me, for I יהוה have sanctified them.](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.23?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Why does the Torah  use the word "Mikdoshay" which sounds plural, if this is referring to the Mishkan, shouldn't it be "Mikdoshi" in singular form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Siftei Chakhamim explains that the word מקדשי refers to the services, and not per se to the Mishkan itself.

> His service is profaned. I.e., מקדשי of the verse does not mean the actual Temple, but rather His service, because the word מקדש can refer to the actual Temple and also to the service performed in the Temple.

Rashi explains the same:

> ולא יחלל את מקדשי THAT HE PROFANE NOT WHAT IS HOLY TO ME — Consequently, if he performs the service it is profaned and thus becomes invalid (Sifra, Emor, Chapter 3 11).

However, it seems that the Malbim had the exact same question as you as why the Torah here uses the plural form of the word Mishkan, instead of saying "Mishkan". (no time for translation, will add that in later):

> ולא יחלל את מקדשי: אמר "מקדשַי" בלשון רבים, כי מוסב בין על מ"ש למעלה שלא יגש להקריב אישי ה' ובין על מ"ש שלא יכנס אל הפרוכת, שהם הקדש והמקדש. ושם "מקדש" מורה על המקדש, והסימן הרבים על כרחך על קדשי המקדש. [ועיין עוד טעם לזה בפר' שמיני (סוף סימן לא)]. ור' יהודה למד "חילול" "חילול" מטמא ששמש שהוא במיתה. וחכמים דסבירא להו דכתיב בתרומה "ומתו בו כי יחללוהו", מלת "בו" ממעט זולתו, והיא הבעל מום. ומובא בסנהדרין (דף פד) ושם גרס רבי אומר. וכן בתוספתא (פרק ?? דכריתות ופרק יב דזבחים).

Comment: The Ralbag agrees to what the Sifsei Chachamim infers from Rashi and spells it out a bit: ולא יחלל את מקדשי כי אני השם מקדשם. ראוי שתדע שאין הכונה בזה חלול בית המקדש שאם היה הענין כן היה אומר אני הש' מקדשו ואולם אמר אני הש' מקדשים ר"ל הקדשים ומזה המקו' למדנו שהבעל מום מחלל עבודתו כשהי' מומו מכמו אלו המומי' החמורים שזכרה התורה כי לזאת הסבה בחרה הורה לזכור היותר קשה שבאלו המומין כמו שביארנו: